# Who caused size change event?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

My application ends up in a resize-loop at certain circumstances. I can set a breakpoint in `DataGrid.OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)` but the cause of the change event is unknown. The debugger says [External Code].

Is there a way to find out what causes the size change events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you attach Snoop (http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to your application, you can monitor events and work out what's first causing your resize.

Also, where it says "[External Code]": if you disable "Just my code" in the debugging options, you'll see the callstack through the .NET framework code, which may give you a clue as to where the loop is coming from.

Comment: I tried to use Snoop, but it does no logging and when my application dies the Snoop Window for my application disappears and while my application is busy resizing the Snoop application is unusable.